# Accepted answer always first when sorting on oldest answers

Tags: discussion, status-bydesign, answers, accepted-answer, sorting

I noticed on Stack Exchange that if an answer to a question is accepted, it is always first when sorting the answers by *oldest* - even if it wasn't the first answer.

Is that by design? Doesn't it break with the very point of sorting by *oldest*/*newest*?

*(One example side-effect: when sorting by oldest to give rep to the one who provided a duplicate answer first, you're intuitively assuming the accepted one was first unless explicitly checking via mouse-over as noted by retracile.)*

Comment: But doesn't it make sense to give the *accepted* answer prominence, even if it overrides the oldest/newest sort order?

Comment: Prominence yes, but losing part of the actual *oldest*/*newest* information (i.e. when you're limited to say *1 hour ago*)?

Comment: You _can_ hover over the time to get the exact timestamp (well, to the second anyway).  Granted, that's not as straightforward.

Comment: Oh, i didn't notice - thats helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is definitely going to be marked "by-design".

However, I too find it frustrating that, If I'm searching for the actual oldest post, the sort order is not what I asked...